# PHP - Comparing Dates

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

In my PHP script I get a date string from my iOS app, as such:

```
$myTime     = $app->request()->post('myTime'); // 2016-08-15 20-02
$date = date('Y-m-d H-i', strtotime($myTime));
```

Now that I have the date from my iOS app, I want to do a check on my database for a booking/reservation, and check if the date from my iOS app falls between a period +/- 10 hours of the date from database:

```
// $book['book_datetime'] is confirmed 2016-08-15 20:38:00

$plusTen = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($book['book_datetime'])+36000);
$minusTen = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($book['book_datetime'])-36000);

if((strtotime($date) > strtotime($minusTen)) && (strtotime($date) < strtotime($plusTen))) {

     //should be true

} else {

}
```

The if statement should be true, however it's not working. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You have a typo. `H-i` should be `H:i`

Comment: You are also over writing `$date` after setting it to a DateTime object you proceed to scrap it with a `date(....)` command????

Comment: @JohnConde sorry, there was actually an error in the comment showing the date. I've updated

Comment: @RiggsFolly - sorry, typo on my posted code. It's edited now....still not working :(

Comment: This `$date = date('Y-m-d H-i', strtotime($myTime));` will not work with your time format. Stick with the DateTime class its more flexible and useful and that would have worked

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H-i', strtotime($myTime));
```

wont work as you have a non standard time format.

Instead use the DateTime class like this to get a timestamp from your odd date time format.

```
$myTime = $app->request()->post('myTime'); // 2016-08-15 20-02
$mydt   = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H-i', $myTime);

$date = $mydt->getTimestamp();
```

Re you comment:

I ran this code from the CLI and it works

```
<?php
$myTime = '2016-08-15 20-02';
$mydt   = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H-i', $myTime);

echo $mydt->getTimestamp() . PHP_EOL;
echo $mydt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
```

If you get an error then maybe you datetime value from `$app->request()->post('myTime');` is not in the format you think

Comment: I'm getting the error: 'Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object'

Comment: Hmmm what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: using version 5.4.43